# How can I plot a regression line in the form of y=Ae^Bx

Tags: python, statistics

Currently I am using the script:

```
a2,b2,c2 = polyfit(x,y,2)
y_predicted = polyval([a2,b2,c2],x)
```

This gives me a formula in the form of

y=ax^2+bx+c

as I am correct? but I want it plotted in the form of:

y=ae^bx

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean? Is it just about plotting or do you also want to fit the data to `y=ae^bx`? Could you provide some data?

Comment: If I compare it with excel you can choose different forms of regression lines. I have a scatterplot but i think the a regression line in the form of y=ae^bx gives a better fit. So I think I also want to fit the data to y=ae^bx.
My dataset is almost a million rows long, so it is hard to give you the dataset\